# Complex IF. formula in Excel

Tags: excel-2016

I checked various posts on IF formulas but I cannot find a way to receive the correct result in my report. I manage deliveries and I would like to calculate the delay days basing on the data from delivery report. The trick is that the delay will depend on the status of delivery, as in each case I have to consider a different date and column in Excel. These are the data:

Status of delivery:

1. Confirmed
2. Unloaded
3. Unloading
4. Not confirmed
5. Started
6. In route
7. Pick-up pending
8. Prepared

This delivery status is updated in C column in my Raw Data report. For each, I will have to calculate the delay in a different way therefore I figured that IF formula could be of use.

Below you can see the columns that contain the relevant dates for the calculations:

[image: Reference columns for calculations]

Status of delivery and reference date:

1. Confirmed - D
2. Unloaded - D
3. Unloading - D
4. Not confirmed - S
5. Started - D
6. In route - S
7. Pick-up pending - E
8. Prepared - S

I made this formula as below, sadly, only the first record is calculated correctly, the rest of the delays is "null".

```
=IF(C2="Confirmed";(TODAY()-D2);IF(C2="Unloaded";(TODAY()-D2);IF(C2="Unloading";(TODAY()-D2);IF(C2="Not confirmed";(TODAY()-S2);IF(C2="Started";(TODAY()-D2);IF(C2="In route";(TODAY()-S2);IF(C2="Pick-up pending";(TODAY()-E2);IF(C2="Prepared";(TODAY()-S2);"null"))))))))
```

Do you happen to have any idea where am I making the error which I don´t see? I will be grateful for any help. If it´s also relevant, I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: There is a limit on how many brackets can "open" in a formula... consider using `OR` as there are doubles like `=IF(OR(C2="Confirmed";C2="Unloaded";C2="Unloading";C2="Started");TODAY()-D2;IF(OR(.....` also check for hidden spaces and stuff like that... and without a better example it will be hard to make suggestions... have you tried the "evaluate formula" at the "formula" tab for one of the "wrong" cases? It might give a clue what is going wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking it down so the long line becomes readable.

```
=IF(C2="Confirmed";
     (TODAY()-D2);
     IF(C2="Unloaded";
       (TODAY()-D2);
       IF(C2="Unloading";
         (TODAY()-D2);
         IF(C2="Not confirmed";
            (TODAY()-S2);
            IF(C2="Started";
              (TODAY()-D2);
              IF(C2="In route";
                (TODAY()-S2);
                IF(C2="Pick-up pending";
                  (TODAY()-E2);
                  IF(C2="Prepared";
                    (TODAY()-S2);
                    "null"
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
```

At first glance, what I'm looking at is basically a vertical lookup schedule here.

So, I created these two colums. One is the text status we're looking for.
The other is the calculated date.

### Single date VLOOKUp

Assuming D2, S2 and E2 are fixed fields I made the formula `=TODAY() - $D$2`

[image: vertical lookup]

Then it's a simple matter of doing the VLOOKUP in the correct field.
Because we're working with a date type field we need to convert the number to text to get a meaning full date. (I used JJ in the screenshot for years because I have a dutch locale)
Then we also need to handle when VLOOKUP can't find anything, for that we use IFERROR.

`=IFERROR(TEXT(VLOOKUP(F6;$A$2:$B$9;2);"MM-DD-YY");"NULL")`

[image: vlookup]

And now you have an easy to expand lookup table you can put anywhere, hide on a worker tab, etc.. where you can calculate your values, where you can add and remove values.

### Many rows, many dates

But, say you have many rows with different statusses and dates, and you wish to know the number of days it'll take. Then this vertical lookup doesn't look so useful because it can only be used for one row.

We can still leverage VLOOKUP to make our life a bit easier

Assuming there are dates in colums D, E and S

`=IFERROR(DATEDIF(TODAY();INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();VLOOKUP(F2;$A$2:$B$9;2;FALSE)));"d");"NULL")`

We use VLOOKUP to see which column we need to look in. We use a number here for column, not a letter.
We then use ADDRESS to get an excel address reference for the current `ROW()`, and the column we found via vlookup
We funnel that through INDIRECT so we can get the value from that targeted cell.
Then we get a DATEDIFference in days from offset today. 
We wrap it all in an IFERROR to keep things clean.

[image: vlookup power]

- *You could use an `INDEX($D2:$S2;0;VLOOKUP($F2;$A$2:$B$9;2;FALSE))` to get the same effect, as pointed out by [Dirk Reichel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5461205/dirk-reichel) but you have to mindful then that the index used is from the start of the matrix range. So here the matrix starts on row D. So D2 is index 1 instead of 4 it is with my original method, so you'd need to adjust the lookup table accordingly.*

Comment: To my eye a `LOOKUP` is the wrong thing to do in that case and using a volatile formula "if there are many rows" seems counterintuitive... why not using `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT`?

Comment: @DirkReichel because I literally never work with excel, I knew what I wanted and google led me to indirect. I don't know any of the features or functions excel has to offer except if, vlookup and iferror. The rest I googled. But then again why I used indirect, it works doesn't it? Also, how will you determine the correct column to look in without a vlookup? With the myriad of IF's? That's a hassle to update then if a string ever changes or new status types are introduced. Looking at index, that could also work, but you have to be mindful of the relative positioning of the column looked up

Comment: It's mainly to avoid volatile functions as it will make excel not freeze after every change. For a task like that I would just use a simple array formula... but as the question was "why isn't my formula working" I skipped offering something different (except small changes for better readability)... however... as the OP doesn't respond, your answer (while looking good itself) seems a wasted... sadly

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful to someone else. I would think Excel would optimize vlookup internally to a set of hashes, making it more efficient than instantiating strings every row to be used in a comparisan function, where a branch prediction fail may occur more.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try the VLOOKUP now with this task, it seems a good idea. I have the same problem as Tschallacka, I never needed to do such operations so I got lost in the code. Responding for Dirk´s question if I checked the spaces - all seemed fine and I triple-checked everything. It must be too many references at once. The thing is that I have to refer to 3 different columns when taking the first date to calculate as the report is huge it always must be the date that corresponds to the given row but in the other column.